# Array#delete_at or Array#slice!? and how to look up implementations

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm scrubbing large data files (+1MM comma-separated rows). An example row might look like this:

```
@row = "123456789,11122,CustomerName,2014-01-31,2014-02-01,RemoveThisEntry,R,SKUInfo,05-MAR-14 05:50:24,SourceID,RemoveThisEntryToo,TransactionalID"
```

Certain columns must be removed from it, after which the row should look like this:

```
@row = "123456789,11122,CustomerName,2014-01-31,2014-02-01,R,SKUInfo,05-MAR-14 05:50:24,SourceID,TransactionalID"
```

**QUESTION 1:**  If I convert a row of data into an `Array`, which method is preferred for removing elements: [Array#delete_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) or [Array#slice!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-slice-21)? I'd like to know which is the more idiomatic option. Performance is a consideration here, and I'm on a Windows machine.

```
def remove_bad_columns
  ary = @row.split(",")
  ary.delete_at(10)
  ary.delete_at(5)
  @row = ary.join(",")
end
```

**QUESTION 2:** I was wondering if one of these methods was implemented using the other. How can I see how the methods are built in ruby? (How `for` is implemented using `each`, for example.)

Comment: You should use Ruby's [`CSV` library](http://ruby-doc.com/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) when processing CSV data. If speed matters, command line tools are usually faster: `cut -d "," -f 1-5,7-10,12 largedatafile.csv`

Comment: Performance does matter here, as the files can contain +6MM rows when looking at a year (or more) of observations. (I should have mentioned that in the question.) I tried using the `CSV` library on the first pass too (because you're definitely right), but the script kept tripping on nasty artifacts in the data -- after so much santizing via string manipulation, I figured I would just try to stick with strings throughout. I hadn't considered a *nix utility like `cut`, and am downloading `cygwin` to give it a try now. Thanks!

Comment: You could always rummage through the MRI Ruby code. It's open and it would allow you to see how things are implemented at a lower level. Be prepared to read C though :) https://github.com/ruby/ruby

Comment: In MRI Ruby, `Array#slice!` is implemented by the function [`rb_ary_slice_bang`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_2/array.c#L3022-L3070), which in the case you only pass a single index to be deleted just [calls `rb_ary_delete_at`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_2/array.c#L3069). `rb_ary_delete_at` is the function that ultimately implements `Array#delete_at` too, via [`rb_delete_at_m`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_2/array.c#L2995-L2998) which just converts the parameter from a Ruby object to a C 'long'.

Comment: If your columns contain embedded commas, you'll be quickly pushed into a corner if you try to split using something as simple as `split(',')`. CSV will handle conditions that simple code can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not really a difference in performance. I would prefer `delete_at` because that reads nicer.

```
require 'benchmark'

def array
  "123456789,11122,CustomerName,2014-01-31,2014-02-01,RemoveThisEntry,R,SKUInfo,05-MAR-14 05:50:24,SourceID,RemoveThisEntryToo,TransactionalID"
end 

def delete_at
  ary = array.dup.split(",")
  ary.delete_at(10)
  ary.delete_at(5)
  @row = ary.join(",")
end

def slice!
  ary = array.dup.split(",")
  ary.slice!(10)
  ary.slice!(5)
  @row = ary.join(",")
end

require 'benchmark'

n = 1_000_000
Benchmark.bmbm(15) do |x|
  x.report("delete_at :")   { n.times do; delete_at; end }
  x.report("slice!    :")   { n.times do; slice!   ; end }
end

# Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------------
# delete_at :       4.560000   0.000000   4.560000 (  4.566496)
# slice!    :       4.580000   0.010000   4.590000 (  4.576767)
# ------------------------------------------ total: 9.150000sec
# 
#                       user     system      total        real
# delete_at :       4.500000   0.000000   4.500000 (  4.505638)
# slice!    :       4.600000   0.000000   4.600000 (  4.613447)
```

Comment: I picked `delete_at` for readability too haha. Thank you for doing the benchmark diligence too -- do you think their similarity means that one is implemented in terms of the other?

Comment: There is no method `deleted_at`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Array#values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-values_at) rather than `delete_at` or `slice!`:

```
def remove_vals(str, *indices)
  ary = str.split(",")
  v = (0...ary.size).to_a - indices
  ary.values_at(*v).join(",")
end

@row = "123456789,11122,CustomerName,2014-01-31,2014-02-01,RemoveThisEntry," +
      "R,SKUInfo,05-MAR-14 05:50:24,SourceID,RemoveThisEntryToo,TransactionalID"

@row = remove_vals(@row, 5, 10)
  #=> "123456789,11122,CustomerName,2014-01-31,2014-02-01,R,SKUInfo," +
  #   "05-MAR-14 05:50:24,SourceID,TransactionalID"
```

`Array#values_at` has the advantage over the other two methods that you don't have to worry about the order in which the elements are removed.

The efficiency of this method is not significantly different than the other two.  If @spickermann would like to add it to his benchmarks, he could use this:

```
def values_at
  ary = array.split(",")
  v = (0...ary.size).to_a - [5,10]
  @row = ary.values_at(*v).join(",")
end
```

Comment: This is an awesome strategy and worked like gangbusters on a small test -- thank you! Using `values_at` has been added to my TODO list...